# Set include_path or zend_extension so requires will work

Tags: php, zend-framework2, include-path

I did some "house cleaning", and now some of my Zend files require_once statements are failing. I had several Zend folders, and have gotten rid of most of them. I need a way of telling the require_once statements which folder to look in. I have tried several things with include_path="..." in the php.ini, but have had no success.

```
include_path=".:/home/paul13/paul13.com/includes/library"
```

doesn't seem to work when added as a separate line in the php.ini file either in the parent folder, or the php.ini file in the "includes" folder.

How do I tell the files within Zend where to look when doing requires?

I have not tried zend_extension, but will look into that now.

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should just make sure you install ZF2 via Composer and you should have no issues with this as it will take care of autoloading etc.

this is a good place to start:

http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*"
    }
}
```

then type

```
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install
```